# Data source path in obiee administration

Tags: linux, jdbc, obiee, administration

I want to know the physical path (in Linux) of data source in OBIEE application, that are created through xmlpserver -> administration -> jdbc connection

Comment: Why? The application uses declarative configuration rather than code for a reason. You're not supposed to touch that.

Comment: My server was unable to start so i configured with same backup.. only data sources details are unable to fetch. Is there any alternative how can i get my data sources details

Comment: Thank you Chris. I accept this as a challange, and happy to share that my problem is resolved.  Required file is available under repository with the name of datasources.xml